# Apache 2.4 WebDAV and MS Word Authetication

Tags: apache, ms-word, kerberos, webdav

A web application written in java produces links to MS Word docx documents in in WebDAV repository on a Debian Linux server. Clicking on one of these links opens MS Word and a form is shown to put in authentication information. Then the document is opend and  can be edited and saved.

Clicking on a link for the next time, one has to go through the whole process of autheticating (fill in the form) again.

Choosing 'Remember me' did not work. They write, the form should then be prefilled, but it isn't.

I want to get rid of this. Most tipps describe that this would be a problem with Basic Auth or Digest Auth and when using Kerberos it could be solved.

After installing Kerberos MIT on this server, I am able to authentication like before, but the problem still exists.

Does anyone have a hint or a solution for this? 
Is there a configuration for MS Word/MS Office Upload center one has to go through? 
Does one have to place any cretentials on the client?
...?

Configuration

- Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
- MS Word 2013

Answer (score 0):

After struggling many hours I get the Office login form pre filled now.

The solution was to delete all *Generic Credetials* in *Windows Credentials* which contain *MicrosoftOffice* and *SSO_POP_Device* and the *credetial for the our server*.
After that I established our server as network drive, which has the sideeffect that my credetials are stored in Windows Credentials, which leads to pre fill the login form.

But the problem that single sign on is not working still exists.